# Python: как можно сделать из моего кода list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

```py
def matrix(base: int, char: str) -> list:
    new_list = []
    space = 0
    for i in range(base // 2 + 1):
        row = [' '] * space + [char] * (base - (2 * space)) + [' '] * space
        space += 1
        new_list.append(row)
    return new_list[::-1]
```

результат должен быть в итоге:

```
[[' ', 'A', ' '], ['A', 'A', 'A']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def matrix(base: int, char: str) -> list:
    new_list = [ [' '] * space + [char] * (base - (2 * space)) + [' '] * space for space in range(base // 2 + 1)]
    return new_list[::-1]

print(matrix(3, 'A'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш пример работает с функцией, если `base > 2` - необходимо дописать логику для неучтённых случаев. Зачем делать разворот списка если генерируется последовательность, от которой зависит порядок - сразу задаём в `range`.

```py
def matrix(base, char, empty=' '):
    if base > 2:
        out = [[empty] * space + [char] * (base - (2 * space)) + [empty] * space 
for space in range(base // 2 + 1, -1, -1)]
    else:
       out = []
    return out
```